# Uncomplicated firewall - DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY implications?

Tags: linux, firewall, ufw

I don't understand what the function of `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY`. Is using `ACCEPT` considered a security risk, if so, why?